# Returning Arrays in the main()

Tags: java, arrays, return

I'm having trouble returning the value of the array, I know I'm returning it wrong, but I don't know how. Help please.

These are the instructions:

> Instructions: Code a method called dogTypes() that prompts for 3
>   different dog types, stores the types in a local array called dogs,
>   and returns the array to the calling statement in the main(). Once the
>   main() gets the array, it will then use a for loop to print the array
>   content on separate lines as indicated below where 9 represents a
>   numeric value so that the label reads "Dog Type 1: " then "Dog Type 2:
>   ", etc. for each dog type retrieved from the array. You can use the
>   loop control variable from the for loop to produce the 9 value. Save
>   the code  in a program called YourLastNameFirstInitialArraysV1.java. 
>   Dog Type 9: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  Dog Type 9: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

    public class BarrazaMArrayV2
    {//BEGIN BarrazaMLE52

      private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
        String[] dog = dogType();

        System.out.printf("Dog Type 1: %S", dog[0]);

        System.out.printf("Dog Type 2: %S", dog[1]);

        System.out.printf("Dog Type 3: %S", dog[2]);


      }


       public static String[] dogType()

       {
         String[] dogType = new String[3];

         System.out.printf("Enter your dog type: ");
         dogType[0] = input.nextLine();

         System.out.printf("Enter your dog type: ");
         dogType[1] = input.nextLine();

         System.out.printf("Enter your dog type: ");
         dogType[2] = input.nextLine();

        return dogType[3];

       }
    }
```

Comment: Just use `return dogtype;`. When you say `return dogType[3];` you are trying to return one String, in this case one that doesn't even exist since there are 3 things in the array and `[3]` would be the 4th.

Answer (score 1):

You are only returning the 3rd index of the array for returning the whole array.
Change this:

```
return dogType[3];
```

to

```
return dogType;
```

Also your array is not having the 3rd index. If you try to access the 3rd index you will get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 1):

you do not return return dogType[3].

You can use:

```
return dogType
```

Answer (score 1):

You are returning array the wrong way.

return dogType[3];

It returns the element at that index but not the array.

Erase [3]

**return dogType;**

Answer (score 1):

I see a few problems.

1. Your function `dogType()` is supposed to return an array of `String`s but you are only returning a single element.
2. The element you are returning does not exist. The `dogType[]` array has indices 0 to 2, there is no index 3.

Resolve both by changing

```
return dogType[3];
```

To

```
return dogType;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to return string instead of array. It is incompatible with return type as return type is string array. So it give you compilation time error.

So return `dogType` instead of `dogType[3]`

```
dogType is array of string
```

and

```
dogtype[3]is just a string of dogType array index 3
```

Comment: it is not `docType` it is `dogType`.

Answer (score 1):

first,i see that you must know the return type of the function, and that the return type of the function dogType() is String[],so you must return a String array.

```
return dogType[3];//return a String object not the String array.
```

so you can try this:

```
return dogType;//return a String array.
```